# Why it is not going to transform `__get__` into `__get__.__get__`?

Tags: python

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) I know that: every function is in fact an object of `class Function`, and, because of descriptor protocol,  an expression like `a.b` will be transferred to `b.__get__(a, type(a))`.

But here `__get__` is still an object (of class Function), then why `b.__get__` will not be further transformed to `__get__.__get__(b, type(b))` ?

Answer (score 1):

The descriptor protocol is not built into Python, it is built into the default types. Both *implementing* (defining `__get__`, ...) and *invoking* (calling `member.__get__(self, type(self)`) the protocol is done by the [`function`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4cacc8c5eab50db8da3140353596f38a01115ca/Objects/funcobject.c#L625-L634) and [`object`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4cacc8c5eab50db8da3140353596f38a01115ca/Objects/object.c#L1158-L1163) types, respectively, as well as others.

Python internally has bare functions and getters, which do not implement `__get__`, `__set__`, ... methods and do not invoke `member.__get__` either. The `FunctionType.__get__` is such a case:

```
>>> def method(self):
...     return self
...
>>> method
<function __main__.method(self)>
>>> method.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x10f4eb378>
>>> method.__get__.__get__
AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute '__get__'
```